# import contents while creating a new openai-gym env

Tags: openai-gym

Use gym_soccer as example, when I import gym_soccer, it's a wrapped ENV.  Classes defined in soccer_env.py wouldn't show-up. 
I think there should be a way to make it work but can't find out.

soccer_env.py

```
import gym
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
class SoccerEnv(gym.Env):
    pass
class Dummy(object):
    pass
```

when you run it in python:

```
import gym_soccer
dir(gym_soccer)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'logger', 'logging', 'register']
```

I would like to see Dummy and SoccerEnv class available to use. Or is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's hide in gym_soccer.envs.Dummy if you add "from gym_soccer.envs.soccer_env import Dummy".